# What is $\langle v^n\rangle$, found from evaluating this integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, statistical-mechanics

$$\langle v^n \rangle=\int_0^\infty v^{n+2}e^{-mv^2/2kT}dv$$

I got $(2kT/m)^{{n+3}/2}Γ({n+2}/2)$

While [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20%28v%5E%7Bn%2B2%7D*exp%28%7B-mv%5E2%7D%2F%7B2kT%7D%29%29dv%20) got what can be seen in the link.

I would like to ask how I can get what Wolfram got, and provided my result in case it shows what I did wrong. Thank you very much.

The problem is also with the units here: the k is Boltzmann's constant with units $m^2kgs^{-2}K^{-1}$, $v$, as I understand, must be velocity ($m/s$), T is in Kelvin, and $m$ in kilograms. My result ends up with the units $(m^2/s^2)^n$, but, as I understand, should be $(m/s)^n$, so it seems a factor of $1/v$ is missing inside the power of $n$ bracket of my result.

Comment: We can't help you find your mistake until you show us your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redoing the calculation independently of Wolfram Alpha, for the antiderivative
$$I=\int v^{n+2} e^{-\frac{m v^2}{2 k T}}\,dv=-2^{\frac{n+1}{2}} v^{n+3} \left(\frac{m v^2}{k T}\right)^{-\frac{n+3}{2} }
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2},\frac{m v^2}{2 k T}\right)$$ and, for the integral
$$\int_0^\infty v^{n+2} e^{-\frac{m v^2}{2 k T}}\,dv=2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}  \left(\frac{m}{k
   T}\right)^{-\frac{n+3}{2} }\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)$$

**Edit**

Change variable
$$v=\frac{\sqrt{2kT}  }{\sqrt{m}}\sqrt{x}\implies dv=\frac{\sqrt{kT} }{\sqrt{2m}  \sqrt{x}}\,dx$$ to make for the antiderivative (I skipped some simplifications)
$$I=\frac{k  T \left(\frac{\sqrt{2k T}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)^{n+1}}{m}\int e^{-x} x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\,dx$$ and 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\,dx=\Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)$$
 What is suspect is that, if you used this change of variable, *may be*, you missed the $\sqrt x$ in $dv$.

Comment: Could you please give some hint as to how you got that? I was rigorous in my own steps, and got $(2kT/m)^{{n+3}/2}Gamma({n+2}/2)$ for the integral.

Comment: I am really at a loss because I don't see anything wrong in my steps, but somehow failed to get what you (and Wolfram) got. If you could point to one or a few critical steps you made towards obtaining that result, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Any hint, please? I don't see how you get to that answer, I get $(2kT/m)^{{n+3}/2}Γ({n+2}/2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I did everything the same except my simplifications, which you missed, led me to a different constant power and Gamma(n+2/2) instead of n+3/2 inside...

Comment: Seems I had the right answer all along, as funny as it is, except Gamma(n+2/2) instead of Gamma(n+3/2) -> could you say why it is Gamma(n+2/2)?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^\infty v^{n+2}e^{-mv^2/2kT}dv
&=\int_0^\infty v^{n+2}e^{-av^2}dv
\qquad a = m/2kT\\
&=\int_0^\infty (u/\sqrt{a})^{n+2}e^{-u^2}du/\sqrt{a}
\qquad u=\sqrt{a}v, dv = du/\sqrt{a}\\
&=\dfrac1{a^{(n+3)/2}}\int_0^\infty u^{n+2}e^{-u^2}du\\
&=\dfrac{(2kT)^{(n+3)/2}}{m^{(n+3)/2}}\dfrac{\Gamma((n+3)/2)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2^{(n+1)/2}\Gamma((n+3)/2)(kT)^{(n+3)/2}}{m^{(n+3)/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you very much!